# Parse query works in API explorer, but not using cURL

Tags: curl, parse-platform

I've run a query on `someClass` with the following query string in the API console (using the master key):

```
where={"objectId": {"$in": ["id1", "id2"]}}
```

This query returns the objects for both IDs. Then, when using the "export to cURL" function, I get:

```
curl -X GET \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: appId" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: apiKey" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: masterKey" \
-G \
--data-urlencode "where={\"objectId\": {\"$in\": [\"id1\", \"id2\"]}}" \
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/someClass
```

However, running this from the terminal returns:

```
{"results":[]}
```

Excluding the where constraint will return all objects of `someClass` normally.

What is wrong here?

Comment: single quote around the where clause ....  'where={"objectI": {"$in": ["id1", "id2"]}}'

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem.